# Auto play audio using WP Maintenance Mode Plugin

Tags: plugins, audio

I am using the plugin ‘WP Maintenance Mode’ to load a under maintenance website on a website.

I would like for audio to play as soon as somebody lands on the website and for audio player to remain invisible.

```
<p style="text-align: center;">BACK SOON</p>

[audio src="https://myWebsite/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/audio.mp3"]
```

This will load the page and show the audio player and it will play when I press play

I have tried

```
[audio src="https://myWebsite/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/audio.mp3 width = "0" height = "0" autoplay=1]
```

to try and get it to play automatically and without the audio player, but no success.

Comment: [The documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/audio-shortcode/) says it's autoplay="on"

Comment: Can you get this to work on a normal page? Is it just the maintenance mode page where this doesn't work?

Comment: Browsers are very particular about things that autoplay, especially things with sound. You may find that what you want isn't possible on some major browsers. As for the WP Maintenance plugin, I don't see that it's related to this question other than circumstance, people might think this is a problem specific to that plugin and vote to close the question

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- First, this code has some syntax issues - the `src` attribute isn't properly closed. Further, as noted by @Rup, `autoplay` should have a value of `on`:

#### Broken tag:

```html
[audio src="https://myWebsite/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/audio.mp3 width = "0" height = "0" autoplay=1]
```

#### Fixed

```html
[audio src="https://myWebsite/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/audio.mp3" width="0" height="0" autoplay="on"]
```

- Second, I'm not 100% sure that WP Maintenance posts can process shortcodes. I would instead use a standard [HTML Audio Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).